# How to output more than one Skolem functions in Z3(Py)

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I am playing with Skolem functions in Z3-Py. In the following lines, I describe the Skolem function that satisfies the formula `Forall x. Exists y. (x>=2) --> (y>1) /\ (y<=x)` interpreted over integers:

```
x = Int('x')

skolem = Function('skolem', IntSort(), IntSort())

ct_0 = (x >= 2)
ct_1 = (skolem(x) > 1)
ct_2 = (skolem(x) <= x)

phi = ForAll([x], Implies(ct_0, And(ct_1,ct_2)))

s = Solver()
s.add(phi)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

Which I understand that it outputs the unique 'model' possible: `y=2` (i.e., `f(x)=2`). It is printed as follows:

```
sat
[skolem = [else -> 2]]
```

I have a preliminary question: why does the function use an `else`? I guess it comes from the fact that "it is only activated" if the antecedent `(x>=2)` holds. But which is the co-domain of the function if it is not the `else` branch (output `2`) the one activated, but the `if` branch?

**But now it comes my actual question**. I solved the same formula, but interpreted over reals:

```
x = Real('x')

skolem = Function('skolem', RealSort(), RealSort())

ct_0 = (x >= 2.0)
ct_1 = (skolem(x) > 1.0)
ct_2 = (skolem(x) <= x)

phi = ForAll([x], Implies(ct_0, And(ct_1,ct_2)))

s = Solver()
s.add(phi)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

And this outputs... the same Skolem function! Is this right?

In case it is, it is still curious, since it could have chosen many others; e.g., `y=1.5`. Then, I would like to ask for another Skolem function to Z3, so I proceed as if I was asking for 5 new models:

```
phi = ForAll([x], Implies(ct_0, And(ct_1,ct_2)))

s = Solver()
s.add(phi)
for i in range(0,5):
  if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    print(m)
    s.add(Not(m))
```

But I get the following error: `Z3Exception: True, False or Z3 Boolean expression expected. Received [skolem = [else -> 2]] of type <class 'z3.z3.ModelRef'>.` I mean, I see Z3 expects Boolean for the negation (which is obvious hehe), so how can I encode the fact that "I add the negation of this Skolem function into the formula", i.e., that I want to find another Skolem function?

Comment: Your formula says `y <= 2`, but your skolem function says `skolem(x) <= x`. Probably not a big deal; but let's fix that first!

Comment: `Not(m)` is meaningless: You cannot take the logical negation of a model. But you're on the right path; make sure you tell the solver the value of the skolem function at the given value is different than what it got before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you're trying to add the negation of your model `m`; but that's not what `Not(m)` means. In fact, `Not(m)` is meaningless: `Not` operates on booleans, not models; which is the bizarre error you're getting.

To do what you're trying to achieve; simply assert that you want a different skolem function:

```py
from z3 import *

x = Real('x')

skolem = Function('skolem', RealSort(), RealSort())

ct_0 = (x >= 2)
ct_1 = (skolem(x) > 1)
ct_2 = (skolem(x) <= 2)

phi = ForAll([x], Implies(ct_0, And(ct_1,ct_2)))

s = Solver()
s.add(phi)

for i in range(0, 5):
  if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    print(m)
    s.add(skolem(x) != i)
```

This prints:

```py
[skolem = [else -> 2]]
[x = 0, skolem = [else -> If(2 <= Var(0), 2, 1/2)]]
[x = 0, skolem = [else -> If(2 <= Var(0), 2, 1/2)]]
[x = 0, skolem = [else -> If(2 <= Var(0), 3/2, 1/2)]]
[x = 0, skolem = [else -> If(2 <= Var(0), 3/2, 1/2)]]
```

Now this is a little hard to read, but I think you can figure it out. A function model is simply a finite-mapping with an `else` clause, which is what a finite function is. The `Var` call refers to its argument. I haven't looked at the definitions z3 provides in detail to make sure they're good, but I have no reason to suspect why not. See if you can work this out for yourself; it's a valuable exercise! Feel free to ask further questions if anything isn't clear.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! First, I do not understand why adding `skolem(x) != i` works, I mean... `i` is just a value from `0` to `5`! I think I am loosing something key... Then, for the printed skolem functions such as `[x = 0, skolem = [else -> If(2 <= Var(0), 2, 1/2)]]`, what I already understand is that if `(x>=2)` does not hold, then that particular `else` (that I must still learn to interpret) is output. Instead, the skolem function `[skolem = [else -> 2]]`, which was the first offered "model", simply outputs `2` no matter what `x` is, which also makes sense. Am I right? Thanks again!

Comment: Think of `skolem = [else -> If(2 <= Var(0), 2, 1/2)` as `skolem(x) = if x >= 2 then 2 else 0.5`. Does that help?